# ERR_CONNECTION en mi sitio

Tags: apache, php5, google-chrome, drupal7

Soy administrador de una web construida en Drupal 7.
Desde hace una semanas que recibo quejas por parte de usuarios del sitio indicando errores como ERR_CONNECTION_RESET, ERR_CONNECTION_TIME_OUT.
Sé que ambos son errores de Chrome. Los he visto muchas veces en otras páginas pero nunca les había dado importancia hasta que ahora tengo problemas con mi propia web.
Buscando una solución, me encuentro con que todas las sugerencias para evitarlos son del lado del cliente:

- Borrar caché navegador
- Revisar que el Firewall o el Antivirus no este bloqueando la página
- Revisar conexión a Internet
- Proxy
- Entre otros..

Dichas soluciones no me sirven ya que yo no puedo decirles a los usuarios que intenten eso.
Consulto por acá buscando sugerencias o recomendaciones del lado del servidor, que me digan que configuración de Apache, de PHP o mismo de Drupal si poseen conocimiento puedo revisar para intentar algo.
Las quejas que recibo en su mayoría se dan cuando ingresan a mi web desde un link externo, osea desde un enlace de otra web hacía la mía, un pdf u otro tipo de documento. Cuando aparece el error, aprietan F5 y al refrescar la página se soluciona, no es constante el error.

Saludos y muchas Gracias !

Comment: conociendo cómo es Drupal, me late que tienes asignada poca RAM al sitio

Comment: Si, muy posiblemente sea problema con ram o con memoria de PHP. Prueba a subir el tiempo de ejecución y a aumentar la memoria de PHP en el servidor.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Después de unos meses, comparto la solución del problema que afortunadamente se resolvió.

El problema estaba en el Balanceador de Carga que utiliza la web llamado F5. Posee un filtro que ante mayor demanda generaba que la página tarde más en cargar y de esos errores.
Es algún tipo de configuración que balanceador, no puedo dar más detalle.

Saludos !

Answer (score 0):

¿Eres capaz de simular el problema desde una máquina tuya que haga la función de cliente contra el servidor?

Si lo consigues, después revisa los logs en el servidor, posiblemente te pueda dar alguna advertencia de falta de memoria o similar.

Procedes a realizar los cambios en el servidor dependiendo del aviso de los logs y podrías solventar el problema.